# Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. Read timed out

Tags: java, tomcat, upload, applet

Other questions on Stack Overflow have addressed this question, but none of the answers provided have helped me to address the issue.

I'm trying to upload a file of anywhere between 10 kB to 16 MB from an applet using Apache HTTP Commons. Everything works fine in my local environment.

I'm receiving the following exception only on my production server (Tomcat 6.0, https://www.dailyrazor.com/), regardless of file size:

```
org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. Read timed out
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:384)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload.parseRequest(ServletFileUpload.java:116)
    at com.actura.helper.UploadHelper.processUpload(UploadHelper.java:92)
    at com.actura.voice.upload.FileUploadServlet.process(FileUploadServlet.java:85)
    at com.actura.voice.upload.FileUploadServlet.doPost(FileUploadServlet.java:75)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.jk.server.JkCoyoteHandler.invoke(JkCoyoteHandler.java:190)
    at org.apache.jk.common.HandlerRequest.invoke(HandlerRequest.java:291)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.invoke(ChannelSocket.java:769)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.processConnection(ChannelSocket.java:698)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket$SocketConnection.runIt(ChannelSocket.java:891)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:690)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

This is the debugging log of Commons IO:

```
2012-Sep-18 11:26:28,446 [TP-Processor5] com.actura.voice.upload.MonitoredDiskFileItemFactory 
  DEBUG inside MonitoredDiskFileItemFactory constructor (listener) 
2012-Sep-18 11:26:28,794 [TP-Processor5] com.actura.voice.upload.MonitoredDiskFileItemFactory 
  DEBUG inside MonitoredDiskFileItemFactory createItem 
2012-Sep-18 11:26:28,800 [TP-Processor5] com.actura.voice.upload.MonitoredDiskFileItem 
  DEBUG inside MonitoredDiskFileItem constructor 
2012-Sep-18 11:26:28,800 [TP-Processor5] com.actura.voice.upload.MonitoredDiskFileItem 
  DEBUG inside getOutputStream() 
2012-Sep-18 11:26:28,802 [TP-Processor5] com.actura.voice.upload.MonitoredOutputStream 
  DEBUG inside MonitoredOutputStream constructor 
2012-Sep-18 11:26:28,803 [TP-Processor5] com.actura.voice.upload.MonitoredOutputStream 
  DEBUG leaving MonitoredOutputStream contructor 
2012-Sep-18 11:26:28,803 [TP-Processor5] com.actura.voice.upload.MonitoredDiskFileItem 
  DEBUG leaving getOutputStream() 
2012-Sep-18 11:26:28,803 [TP-Processor5] com.actura.voice.upload.MonitoredDiskFileItemFactory 
  DEBUG inside MonitoredDiskFileItemFactory createItem 
2012-Sep-18 11:26:28,803 [TP-Processor5] com.actura.voice.upload.MonitoredDiskFileItem 
  DEBUG inside MonitoredDiskFileItem constructor 
2012-Sep-18 11:26:28,803 [TP-Processor5] com.actura.voice.upload.MonitoredDiskFileItem 
  DEBUG inside getOutputStream() 
2012-Sep-18 11:26:28,803 [TP-Processor5] com.actura.voice.upload.MonitoredOutputStream 
  DEBUG inside MonitoredOutputStream constructor 
2012-Sep-18 11:26:28,803 [TP-Processor5] com.actura.voice.upload.MonitoredOutputStream 
  DEBUG leaving MonitoredOutputStream contructor 
2012-Sep-18 11:26:28,803 [TP-Processor5] com.actura.voice.upload.MonitoredDiskFileItem 
  DEBUG leaving getOutputStream() 
2012-Sep-18 11:26:28,803 [TP-Processor5] com.actura.voice.upload.MonitoredDiskFileItemFactory 
  DEBUG inside MonitoredDiskFileItemFactory createItem 
2012-Sep-18 11:26:28,803 [TP-Processor5] com.actura.voice.upload.MonitoredDiskFileItem 
  DEBUG inside MonitoredDiskFileItem constructor 
2012-Sep-18 11:26:28,803 [TP-Processor5] com.actura.voice.upload.MonitoredDiskFileItem 
  DEBUG inside getOutputStream() 
2012-Sep-18 11:26:28,803 [TP-Processor5] com.actura.voice.upload.MonitoredOutputStream 
  DEBUG inside MonitoredOutputStream constructor 
2012-Sep-18 11:26:28,803 [TP-Processor5] com.actura.voice.upload.MonitoredOutputStream 
  DEBUG leaving MonitoredOutputStream contructor 
2012-Sep-18 11:26:28,804 [TP-Processor5] com.actura.voice.upload.MonitoredDiskFileItem 
  DEBUG leaving getOutputStream() 
2012-Sep-18 11:26:28,804 [TP-Processor5] com.actura.voice.upload.MonitoredDiskFileItemFactory 
  DEBUG inside MonitoredDiskFileItemFactory createItem 
2012-Sep-18 11:26:28,804 [TP-Processor5] com.actura.voice.upload.MonitoredDiskFileItem 
  DEBUG inside MonitoredDiskFileItem constructor 
2012-Sep-18 11:26:28,804 [TP-Processor5] com.actura.voice.upload.MonitoredDiskFileItem 
  DEBUG inside getOutputStream() 
2012-Sep-18 11:26:28,804 [TP-Processor5] com.actura.voice.upload.MonitoredOutputStream 
  DEBUG inside MonitoredOutputStream constructor 
2012-Sep-18 11:26:28,804 [TP-Processor5] com.actura.voice.upload.MonitoredOutputStream 
  DEBUG leaving MonitoredOutputStream contructor 
2012-Sep-18 11:26:28,804 [TP-Processor5] com.actura.voice.upload.MonitoredDiskFileItem 
  DEBUG leaving getOutputStream() 
 processing folder... /home/dixieh83/public_html/ActuraVoiceRecorderDemo/temp
2012-Sep-18 11:27:47,062 [TP-Processor4] com.actura.voice.upload.MonitoredDiskFileItemFactory 
  DEBUG inside MonitoredDiskFileItemFactory constructor (listener) 
2012-Sep-18 11:27:47,461 [TP-Processor4] com.actura.voice.upload.MonitoredDiskFileItemFactory 
  DEBUG inside MonitoredDiskFileItemFactory createItem 
2012-Sep-18 11:27:47,461 [TP-Processor4] com.actura.voice.upload.MonitoredDiskFileItem 
  DEBUG inside MonitoredDiskFileItem constructor 
2012-Sep-18 11:27:47,462 [TP-Processor4] com.actura.voice.upload.MonitoredDiskFileItem 
  DEBUG inside getOutputStream() 
2012-Sep-18 11:27:47,462 [TP-Processor4] com.actura.voice.upload.MonitoredOutputStream 
  DEBUG inside MonitoredOutputStream constructor 
2012-Sep-18 11:27:47,462 [TP-Processor4] com.actura.voice.upload.MonitoredOutputStream 
  DEBUG leaving MonitoredOutputStream contructor 
2012-Sep-18 11:27:47,462 [TP-Processor4] com.actura.voice.upload.MonitoredDiskFileItem 
  DEBUG leaving getOutputStream() 
2012-Sep-18 11:27:47,462 [TP-Processor4] com.actura.voice.upload.MonitoredDiskFileItemFactory 
  DEBUG inside MonitoredDiskFileItemFactory createItem 
2012-Sep-18 11:27:47,462 [TP-Processor4] com.actura.voice.upload.MonitoredDiskFileItem 
  DEBUG inside MonitoredDiskFileItem constructor 
2012-Sep-18 11:27:47,462 [TP-Processor4] com.actura.voice.upload.MonitoredDiskFileItem 
  DEBUG inside getOutputStream() 
2012-Sep-18 11:27:47,462 [TP-Processor4] com.actura.voice.upload.MonitoredOutputStream 
  DEBUG inside MonitoredOutputStream constructor 
2012-Sep-18 11:27:47,462 [TP-Processor4] com.actura.voice.upload.MonitoredOutputStream 
  DEBUG leaving MonitoredOutputStream contructor 
2012-Sep-18 11:27:47,462 [TP-Processor4] com.actura.voice.upload.MonitoredDiskFileItem 
  DEBUG leaving getOutputStream() 
2012-Sep-18 11:27:47,463 [TP-Processor4] com.actura.voice.upload.MonitoredDiskFileItemFactory 
  DEBUG inside MonitoredDiskFileItemFactory createItem 
2012-Sep-18 11:27:47,463 [TP-Processor4] com.actura.voice.upload.MonitoredDiskFileItem 
  DEBUG inside MonitoredDiskFileItem constructor 
2012-Sep-18 11:27:47,463 [TP-Processor4] com.actura.voice.upload.MonitoredDiskFileItem 
  DEBUG inside getOutputStream() 
2012-Sep-18 11:27:47,463 [TP-Processor4] com.actura.voice.upload.MonitoredOutputStream 
  DEBUG inside MonitoredOutputStream constructor 
2012-Sep-18 11:27:47,463 [TP-Processor4] com.actura.voice.upload.MonitoredOutputStream 
  DEBUG leaving MonitoredOutputStream contructor 
2012-Sep-18 11:27:47,463 [TP-Processor4] com.actura.voice.upload.MonitoredDiskFileItem 
  DEBUG leaving getOutputStream() 
2012-Sep-18 11:27:47,463 [TP-Processor4] com.actura.voice.upload.MonitoredDiskFileItemFactory 
  DEBUG inside MonitoredDiskFileItemFactory createItem 
2012-Sep-18 11:27:47,463 [TP-Processor4] com.actura.voice.upload.MonitoredDiskFileItem 
  DEBUG inside MonitoredDiskFileItem constructor 
2012-Sep-18 11:27:47,463 [TP-Processor4] com.actura.voice.upload.MonitoredDiskFileItem 
  DEBUG inside getOutputStream() 
2012-Sep-18 11:27:47,463 [TP-Processor4] com.actura.voice.upload.MonitoredOutputStream 
  DEBUG inside MonitoredOutputStream constructor 
2012-Sep-18 11:27:47,463 [TP-Processor4] com.actura.voice.upload.MonitoredOutputStream 
  DEBUG leaving MonitoredOutputStream contructor 
2012-Sep-18 11:27:47,463 [TP-Processor4] com.actura.voice.upload.MonitoredDiskFileItem 
  DEBUG leaving getOutputStream()
```

Other than this upload issue my applet works fine.

This is the configuration of the server as described in my production server's `server.xml` file:

```
<!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 --> <Connector address="127.0.0.1" port="9609" enableLookups="false" protocol="AJP/1.3" connectionTimeout="30000" maxThreads="50" minSpareThreads="1" maxSpareThreads="3" disableUploadTimeout="true" />
```

The speed of my internet connection is fine (2.01 Mbps down and 0.42 Mbps up), so this exception leaves me puzzled. I've already set `connectionTimeOut` to 3000000, but I still got the exception. Should I set `connectionTimeOut` to -1 to make it unlimited?

File permissions are set to `777` on the directory from which I'm uploading and I'm using JDK version 7 to run the applet in the browser.

Java console output:

```
Java Plug-in 10.7.2.10
Using JRE version 1.7.0_07-b10 Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
```

When the upload fails, I get this in the console:

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.write(AbstractSessionOutputBuffer.java:169)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.ContentLengthOutputStream.write(ContentLengthOutputStream.java:119)
    at org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.InputStreamBody.writeTo(InputStreamBody.java:70)
    at org.apache.http.entity.mime.HttpMultipart.doWriteTo(HttpMultipart.java:206)
    at org.apache.http.entity.mime.HttpMultipart.writeTo(HttpMultipart.java:224)
    at org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity.writeTo(MultipartEntity.java:183)
    at org.apache.http.entity.HttpEntityWrapper.writeTo(HttpEntityWrapper.java:98)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.EntityEnclosingRequestWrapper$EntityWrapper.writeTo(EntityEnclosingRequestWrapper.java:108)
    at org.apache.http.impl.entity.EntitySerializer.serialize(EntitySerializer.java:122)
    at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.sendRequestEntity(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:271)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.sendRequestEntity(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:197)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doSendRequest(HttpRequestExecutor.java:257)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:125)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:712)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:517)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:1066)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:1044)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:1035)
    at com.actura.app.util.ApplicationUtil.uploadUsingApache(ApplicationUtil.java:143)
    at com.actura.app.util.ApplicationUtil.saveWaveToServer(ApplicationUtil.java:90)
    at com.actura.app.capture.RecorderUI.saveButtonActionPerformed(RecorderUI.java:1856)
    at com.actura.app.capture.RecorderUI.access$17(RecorderUI.java:1824)
    at com.actura.app.capture.RecorderUI$7.actionPerformed(RecorderUI.java:1325)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

**i have come to know that this might be a problem of my ISP. I just wonder if it is the problem of iSP why i can smoothly uses software like temviewer and Skype ??**

The following is the code that performs the upload:

```
public static String uploadUsingApache(URL url, List<File> list,
            String userId, String accountId, String waveDuration)
            throws Exception {

        // The execution:
        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpPost method = new HttpPost(url.toString());

        MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();
        entity.addPart("userId", new StringBody(userId, Charset
                .forName("UTF-8")));
        entity.addPart(IVR_ACCOUNT_KEY, new StringBody(accountId, Charset
                .forName("UTF-8")));
        entity.addPart(IVR_MP3LEN_KEY, new StringBody(waveDuration, Charset
                .forName("UTF-8")));

        // FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(list.get(0));
        // entity.addPart("file", fileBody);

        for (File f : list) {

            byte[] imageBytes = fileToByteArray(f);
            entity.addPart("attachment_field", new InputStreamKnownSizeBody(
                    new ByteArrayInputStream(imageBytes), imageBytes.length,
                    "audio/wav", f.getName()));
            method.setEntity(entity);
        }

        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();

        // HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(method,responseHandler);
        String responseText = httpclient.execute(method, responseHandler);

        // error text
        if (responseText.contains("<exception>")) {
            responseText = responseText.replace("<exception>", "");
            responseText = responseText.replace("</exception>", "");
            throw new Exception(responseText);
        }

        // System.out.println(" Status " +response.getStatusLine());
        List<String> deleteList = Arrays.asList(responseText.split(","));

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        int cnt = 1;
        for (File f : list) {
            if (deleteList.contains(f.getName())) {
                sb.append(f.getName() + (cnt == deleteList.size() ? "" : ", "));
                f.delete();
                cnt++;
            }

        }

        if (deleteList.size() > 1) {
            sb.append(" are ");
        } else if (deleteList.size() == 1) {
            sb.append(" is ");
        } else {

        }

        sb.append(" successfully saved.");

        return sb.toString();
    }
```

When I press the upload button on my applet's GUI, it calls above method and at the same time the GUI freezes. 10 to 50 seconds later, the server throws the `FileUploadException`. The servlet notifies the applet about the exception, but the applet hangs for four or five minutes before notifying the user of the exception.

Why is there so much delay if there's something wrong on the server side?

Comment: It would be helpful if you linked to the similar question(s) that you'd already seen posted, and in particular if you detail what steps you have already tried, why they don't work for you, and how your environment differs from those where that solution did work.

Comment: What version of Java are you running the applet on in the browser? Does the applet load and work fine other than this upload functionality?

Comment: yes i am using Jdk 7 for the applet running. the applet works fine other than this upload functionality. is there any issue with upload speed ??

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This helped me out a lot: http://blog.somepixels.net/en/502-proxy-error-uploading-from-apache-mod_proxy-to-tomcat-7/

Basically in my server.xml I set it as:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" URIEncoding="UTF-8"
       connectionUploadTimeout="36000000" disableUploadTimeout="false"
       connectionTimeout="60000" redirectPort="8443" />
```

Comment: [connectionUploadTimeout]: Specifies the timeout, in milliseconds, to use while a data upload is in progress. This only takes effect if disableUploadTimeout is set to false.

[disableUploadTimeout]: This flag allows the servlet container to use a different, usually longer connection timeout during data upload. If not specified, this attribute is set to true which disables this longer timeout.

[source]: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html

Answer (score 4):

It's not clear from the question what config you're running with (or what you've already tried), but the problem is almost by definition that the socket timeout is exceeded during the upload.

The error is thrown because the file was not fully received before the relevant timeout was reached.  This is consistent with things working in test (on a local network) but not when running over the much slower internet (especially when it comes to upload speeds).

Have a look at your `server.xml` for the relevant `<Connector>` definition.  You'll be interested in the value of either the `connectionTimeout` or `connectionUploadTimeout` attributes (the latter if `disableUploadTimeout` is set to true).

In the absence of evidence of more nefarious problems, I expect you can resolve this issue simply by increasing the connection timeout(s).

Comment: this is the xml i copied from my production server's server.xml .      <!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
    <Connector address="127.0.0.1" port="9609" enableLookups="false" protocol="AJP/1.3" 
               connectionTimeout="30000" maxThreads="50" minSpareThreads="1" maxSpareThreads="3" disableUploadTimeout="true" />

Comment: also my internet speed is very well , i don't understand what is the problem when it comes to production server , should i make connectionTimeOut to -1 for make it unlimited ??

Comment: i have just check my speed with speedtest.com and the result is        download speed is 2.01 mbps and upload speed is 0.42 mbps i have set the connectionTimeout to 3000000 but the same exception . how can i get rid of this ?