# Exception multipart/form-data request failed. Read timed out

Tags: java, file-upload

I have found below link that was a similier question with mine. But I think it is still been questioning to writer. 
--> [Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. Read timed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12476604/processing-of-multipart-form-data-request-failed-read-timed-out)

Server Env. :  Jre1.6 and Tomcat 6.0, Tomcat 7.0 
Both Tomcat are running. 
My website is deployed in 6.0.
server.xml

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" URIEncoding="UTF-8"
   connectionUploadTimeout="36000000" disableUploadTimeout="false"
   connectionTimeout="60000" redirectPort="8443" />
```

When I upload a file about 900Mbytes big, It caused the problem(much smaller is fine). 
every I submit my form, the error event is showed after regular intervals(approx.. 7~8min).

Plsase show me the sunshine.

```
org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Could not parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$IOFileUploadException: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. Read timed out
at org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver.parseRequest(CommonsMultipartResolver.java:162)
at org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver.resolveMultipart(CommonsMultipartResolver.java:138)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.checkMultipart(DispatcherServlet.java:887)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:750)
at com.mytest.framework.web.servlet.ExDispatcherServlet.doDispatch(ExDispatcherServlet.java:42)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at com.mytest.common.filter.AuthorityFilter.doFilter(AuthorityFilter.java:95)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at com.mytest.common.filter.AccessFilter.doFilter(AccessFilter.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$IOFileUploadException: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. Read timed out
at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:359)
at org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload.parseRequest(ServletFileUpload.java:126)
at org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver.parseRequest(CommonsMultipartResolver.java:155)
... 31 more 
         Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalInputBuffer.fill(InternalInputBuffer.java:751)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalInputBuffer$InputStreamInputBuffer.doRead(InternalInputBuffer.java:781)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.IdentityInputFilter.doRead(IdentityInputFilter.java:116)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalInputBuffer.doRead(InternalInputBuffer.java:710)
at org.apache.coyote.Request.doRead(Request.java:427)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.realReadBytes(InputBuffer.java:304)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.substract(ByteChunk.java:419)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.read(InputBuffer.java:327)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream.read(CoyoteInputStream.java:193)
at org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream$ItemInputStream.makeAvailable(MultipartStream.java:959)
at org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream$ItemInputStream.read(MultipartStream.java:887)
at java.io.InputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.commons.fileupload.util.Streams.copy(Streams.java:94)
at org.apache.commons.fileupload.util.Streams.copy(Streams.java:64)
at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:354)
... 33 more
```

Comment: When I do that on Developer server, It's clearly uploaded. But Real server has got a sick.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set `maxPostSize` attribute to the `<Connector..>`. The default post size would be `2MB` if not specified.

- Set `maxPostSize="0"` for unlimited data upload.

Comment: thanks mate. I did changed some params on <connector... then another issue poped up.

Comment: Caused by: org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$IOFileUploadException: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. Stream ended unexpectedly
 at org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:359)
 at org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload.parseRequest(ServletFileUpload.java:126)
 at org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver.parseRequest(CommonsMultipartResolver.java:155)
 ... 31 more

Comment: "Stream ended unexpectedly".... Do you think it can caused by Firewall? that server set in such a government office.

Comment: It seems like a socket timeout. Do you have any other exceptions down the stack trace?

Comment: no.. it's still showing the error "Stream ended unexpectedly". Uploading 300mb mp4 is always fine.

Answer (score 1):

If someone tries to upload a file, then changes the browser URL (clicks a link, opens a bookmark, etc) or if you redirect it to other URL in Code then you could get that exception.

This can be fixed by using `CallableThread`