# Upload file stop with Unexpected EOF read on the socket Exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

Sometime when I try to upload a file on my remote vps i get this exception (the upload proccess stop in 60%)

```
06-Jan-2016 11:59:36.801 SEVERE [http-nio-54000-exec-9] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [mvc-dispatcher] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed;
nested exception is org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Could not parse multipart servlet request;
nested exception is org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadBase$IOFileUploadException: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. Unexpected EOF read on the socket]
with root cause
 java.io.EOFException: Unexpected EOF read on the socket
```

and in `Google Chrome` the connextion is lost like the server is down, i get `ERR_CONNECTION_ABORTED`

i upload file like this in spring mvc

```
public void save_file(MultipartFile upfile , String path){

        try {

            File fichier = new File( path ) ;
            byte[] bytes = upfile.getBytes();
            BufferedOutputStream stream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream( fichier ));
            stream.write(bytes);
            stream.close();
            System.out.println( "You successfully uploaded " + upfile.getOriginalFilename() + "!" );

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println( "You failed to upload " + upfile.getOriginalFilename() + " => " + e.getMessage() ); ;
        }

}
```

my controller :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/administration/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String Upload_AO_journal(
        @ModelAttribute  UploadForm uploadForm,
                Model map , HttpServletRequest request, HttpSession session ) throws ParseException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
```

my bean

```
public class UploadForm {

    ...
    public MultipartFile scan;
```

So how can solve this problem ?

Comment: Does it fail for all file sizes, or do small files succeed?  Can you share the spring specific code that maps the request to this method?

Comment: @tdimmig sometimes it fails and sometimes for the same size it's okey !! i update my question.

Comment: See if this answer can help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18543887/4056187

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried stream?

Jsp code:

`<form method="POST" onsubmit="" ACTION="url?${_csrf.parameterName}=${_csrf.token}" ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data">`

Controller:

```
 @RequestMapping(
        value = "url", method = RequestMethod.POST
)
public void uploadFile(
        @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file
) throws IOException {

 InputStream input = upfile.getInputStream();
 Path path = Paths.get(path);//check path
 OutputStream output = Files.newOutputStream(path);
 IOUtils.copy(in, out); //org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils or you can create IOUtils.copy

}
```

All that worked for me with spring 4.0 and spring security.

Secondly, you should check if the http connection is timeout. Chrome does not support that configuration. So you can use firefox and follow here http://morgb.blogspot.com.es/2014/05/firefox-29-and-http-response-timeout.html.

Comment: The apache api for file is more secure than the default java api for files ?

Comment: I used it, just because it is clean and tested. I donot think it  is more secure.

Comment: @Youssef I am facing a similar issue, but in my case I am closing the streams in a finally block. Is it not required to close the input and output streams here?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about the getBytes() method on the upfile.  A more suitable approach would be to use the InputStream which will manage any size file and will buffer when necessary.  Something like:

```
public void save_file(MultipartFile upfile , String path){

    try {
        File fichier = new File( path ) ;
        BufferedOutputStream stream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream( fichier ));
        InputStream is = upfile.getInputStream();
        byte [] bytes = new byte[1024];
        int sizeRead;
        while ((sizeRead = is.read(bytes,0, 1024)) > 0) {
            stream.write(bytes, 0, sizeRead);
        }
        stream.flush();
        stream.close();
        System.out.println( "You successfully uploaded " + upfile.getOriginalFilename() + "!" );

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println( "You failed to upload " + upfile.getOriginalFilename() + " => " + e.getMessage() ); ;
    }

}
```

Comment: why `new byte[1024]` ? the size will be devided by 1024 ?

Comment: you could make it any size you need, 1024 is 1K and usually is the most performant size for downloading.  Have you tried it?

Comment: Not yet when i go home i will try it

Answer (score 2):

This issue appears because you close stream until stream write whole data.

Wrong way:

```
stream.write(bytes);
stream.close();
```

Right way:

```
try (BufferedOutputStream stream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fichier))) 
{
    stream.write(data);
}
```

You should close your stream after whole data is written.

Comment: Sure, stream.close() should put into the finally block.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issues and problem is when you are uploading file you are using Multipart Form POST Request. You can read about [MIME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME) .

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=frontier

This is a message with multiple parts in MIME format.
--frontier
Content-Type: text/plain

This is the body of the message.
--frontier
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

PGh0bWw+CiAgPGhlYWQ+CiAgPC9oZWFkPgogIDxib2R5PgogICAgPHA+VGhpcyBpcyB0aGUg
Ym9keSBvZiB0aGUgbWVzc2FnZS48L3A+CiAgPC9ib2R5Pgo8L2h0bWw+Cg==
--frontier--
```

Basically issue I had was that multipart from request has meta information part, text part and actual file encoded I believe in base64. Each of this parts are split by boundary. If you don't set up this boundary (in example above it's called "frontier") correctly server starts reading the file but doesn't know where it ends until it reaches EOF and returns error about unexpected EOF because it didn't found required boundaries.

Problem with your code is that you are writing file into ByteOutputStream which is suitable when returning file from server to the user not other way around. Server is expecting this Multipart request with some standard predefined formatting. Use [Apache Commons HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/) library that does all this request formating and boundary setting for you. If you use Maven then [this link](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-httpclient/commons-httpclient).

```
File f = new File("/path/fileToUpload.txt");
PostMethod filePost = new PostMethod("http://host/some_path");
Part[] parts = {
  new StringPart("param_name", "value"),
  new FilePart(f.getName(), f)
};
filePost.setRequestEntity(
  new MultipartRequestEntity(parts, filePost.getParams())
  );
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
int status = client.executeMethod(filePost);
```

Disclaimer: code is not mine it's example from [Apache website for multipart request](https://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/methods/multipart/MultipartRequestEntity.html)

Comment: Well from his question I understood that he's uploading from Spring Client because he said "i upload file like this in spring mvc" that's why I assumed he's uploading from client

Comment: I guess he meant something like 'into'.  He is uploading using google chrome on the client and has Spring MVC on the server side.

Comment: @MichaelDD yes i use browser

Comment: Oh ok my apologies I didn't correctly understand the question. I was having same issue when uploading from client so I assume that's your case as well

Comment: No problem bro .. i can face your problem in the future

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when I didn't properly set the path where the file is going to be placed.

The fix was to change it like this:

```java
factoryMaster.setCertificateFile("E:\\Project Workspace\\Live Projects\\fileStore\\Factory Master\\"+factoryMasterBean.getFile().getOriginalFilename());
```

and use throws exception in controller:

```
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<FactoryMaster> saveFactoryMaster(@ModelAttribute("factoryMasterBean") FactoryMasterBean factoryMasterBean,FactoryMaster factoryMaster) throws IllegalStateException, IOException {...............}
```

and make sure do not send any file with the same name which already exists.