# I get error java.io.EOFException: Unexpected EOF read on the socket when tried get MultipartFile file

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, multipartform-data

I have js function for upload fiels and another data

```
function uploadFormData(){
            var oMyForm = new FormData();
            oMyForm.append("file", file2.files[0]);
            oMyForm.append("resolutionName", document.getElementById("ruling-name").value);
            $.ajax({
                url: '/add',
                data: oMyForm,
                dataType: 'text',
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                type: 'POST',
                success: function(data){ 
                }
            });
        }
```

And I have spring boot controller with method for recive this data

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView add(MultipartHttpServletRequest request) {

        Iterator<String> itr =  request.getFileNames();
        MultipartFile mpf = request.getFile(itr.next());    
        try {
            UploadedFile ufile = new UploadedFile();
            ufile.length = mpf.getBytes().length;
            ufile.bytes= mpf.getBytes();
            ufile.type = mpf.getContentType();
            ufile.name = mpf.getOriginalFilename();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return new ModelAndView("index");
    }
```

This work fine. But I want change construction from

```
public ModelAndView add(MultipartHttpServletRequest request)
```

to

```
public ModelAndView add(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, @RequestParam("resolutionName") String resolutionName)
```

But I get an error

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Could not parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is java.io.IOException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$IOFileUploadException: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. Unexpected EOF read on the socket
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:726) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:471) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:394) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:311) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:395) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:254) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.throwable(StandardHostValve.java:349) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:175) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:784) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:802) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1410) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_60]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_60]
Caused by: org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Could not parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is java.io.IOException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$IOFileUploadException: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. Unexpected EOF read on the socket
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.parseRequest(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:111) ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.<init>(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:85) ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardServletMultipartResolver.resolveMultipart(StandardServletMultipartResolver.java:76) ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.checkMultipart(DispatcherServlet.java:1099) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:932) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    ... 26 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$IOFileUploadException: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. Unexpected EOF read on the socket
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParts(Request.java:2874) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParameters(Request.java:3176) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getParameter(Request.java:1110) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getParameter(RequestFacade.java:381) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:70) ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    ... 12 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$IOFileUploadException: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. Unexpected EOF read on the socket
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:297) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParts(Request.java:2801) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    ... 27 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Unexpected EOF read on the socket
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.fill(Http11InputBuffer.java:747) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.access$400(Http11InputBuffer.java:38) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer$SocketInputBuffer.doRead(Http11InputBuffer.java:1073) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.IdentityInputFilter.doRead(IdentityInputFilter.java:100) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.doRead(Http11InputBuffer.java:303) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.coyote.Request.doRead(Request.java:511) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.realReadBytes(InputBuffer.java:318) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.checkEof(ByteChunk.java:397) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.substract(ByteChunk.java:379) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.read(InputBuffer.java:338) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream.read(CoyoteInputStream.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.util.LimitedInputStream.read(LimitedInputStream.java:132) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.MultipartStream$ItemInputStream.makeAvailable(MultipartStream.java:977) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.MultipartStream$ItemInputStream.read(MultipartStream.java:881) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.util.LimitedInputStream.read(LimitedInputStream.java:132) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:107) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.util.Streams.copy(Streams.java:98) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.util.Streams.copy(Streams.java:68) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:293) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    ... 28 common frames omitted
```

I tried add change contentType to `"multipart/form-data"` like in [this ansver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34634455/upload-file-stop-with-unexpected-eof-read-on-the-socket-exception)