# SocketTimeoutException Spring 4

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat8

I am using spring MVC 4 with tomcat 8. while uploading file I am receiving following error. I have configured session to expire after an hour.Can anyone guide me in right direction

```
Could not parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is java.io.IOException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$IOFileUploadException: Processing of multipart/form-data request failed. null] with root cause
 java.net.SocketTimeoutException
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioBlockingSelector.read(NioBlockingSelector.java:201)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.read(NioSelectorPool.java:235)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.read(NioSelectorPool.java:216)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.fillReadBuffer(NioEndpoint.java:1233)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.read(NioEndpoint.java:1182)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.fill(Http11InputBuffer.java:708)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.access$300(Http11InputBuffer.java:40)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer$SocketInputBuffer.doRead(Http11InputBuffer.java:1057)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.IdentityInputFilter.doRead(IdentityInputFilter.java:139) ...
```

In controller :

```
@PostMapping(value = "/uploadSurvey")
    @ResponseBody
public String uploadSurvey(@Valid FileBucket fileBucket, BindingResult result, HttpSession session) {

        if (result.hasErrors())
            return "redirect:/surveys/uploadSurvey";
        else {

            byte[] bytes;
            try {
                bytes = fileBucket.getFile().getBytes();
                String decoded = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
                //Here I do object mapping using jackson
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
         }
      return "xxx";
    }
```

on client side i am using angularjs to send the file:

```
fd.append('file', file);
        fd.append($scope.csrfParamName, $scope.csrfToken);

        $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
            transformRequest : angular.identity,
            headers : {
                'Content-Type' : undefined
            }
        })
```

Comment: add your code. client and server. so you read this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34634455/upload-file-stop-with-unexpected-eof-read-on-the-socket-exception

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you found the solution?